# CUDA device pointer manipulation

Tags: pointers, cuda

I've used:

```
float *devptr;
//...
cudaMalloc(&devptr, sizeofarray);
cudaMemcpy(devptr, hostptr, sizeofarray, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

in CUDA C to allocate and populate an array.
Now I'm trying to run a cuda kernel, e.g.:

```
__global__ void kernelname(float *ptr)
{
   //...
}
```

in that array but with an offset value.
In C/C++ it would be someting like this:

```
kernelname<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(devptr+offset);
```

However, this doesn't seem to work.

Is there a way to do this without sending the offset value to the kernel in a separate argument and use that offset in the kernel code?
Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pointer arithmetic does work just fine in CUDA. You can add an offset to a CUDA pointer in host code and it will work correctly (remembering the offset isn't a byte offset, it is a plain word or element offset).

EDIT: A simple working example:

```
#include <cstdio>
int main(void)
{

    const int na = 5, nb = 4;
    float a[na] = { 1.2, 3.4, 5.6, 7.8, 9.0 };
    float *_a, b[nb];

    size_t sza = size_t(na) * sizeof(float);
    size_t szb = size_t(nb) * sizeof(float);

    cudaFree(0);

    cudaMalloc((void **)&_a, sza );
    cudaMemcpy( _a, a, sza, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy( b, _a+1, szb, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    for(int i=0; i<nb; i++)
        printf("%d %f\n", i, b[i]);

    cudaThreadExit();
}
```

Here, you can see a word/element offset has been applied to the device pointer in the second `cudaMemcpy` call to start the copy from the second word, not the first.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know that it isn't a byte offset, however, I don't know what a word size is. I was simply adding the index number from which I needed the pointer, just like I do in C++. Is that correct?

Comment: Thank you for your time. It was very helpful. It's working now. It was a stupid error. I'm truly sorry.

Comment: Hi talonmies. What do you mean with word size offset? Doesn't that depend on the type of the array you are trying to allocate? If the array in your example was of type char than _a+1 points to a[1], and not a[3] right?

Comment: Question: If I have a char * on the GPU, would the offset be in bytes or words (4bytes)?

Comment: The offset is always the number of elements of the type, not the number of bytes. If you want to offset by one array element, the offset is +1, irrespective of the type

Comment: Someone tried to edit your answer to change 'word' to 'element'. I'm skipping the review personally (I don't know cuda) but it's already got a Reject vote. Just letting you know in case that change is actually correct.

Comment: If I have 40 char arrays, it means a CUdeviceptr(unsigned int) can have 40 x 100MB ranges. Does this mean if I accidentally increment end of an array and fall into next array's first item? What if I need to use more than 4GB addressing for whole project? How does it map all of them into unsigned int? Should I use something else than cuMemAlloc

Answer (score 2):

Pointer arithmetic does work on host side code, it's used fairly often in the example code provided by nvidia.

"Linear memory exists on the device in a 40-bit address space, so separately allocated entities can reference one another via pointers, for example, in a binary tree."

Read more at: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#ixzz4KialMz00

And from the performance primitives (npp) documentation, a perfect example of pointer arithmetic.

"4.5.1    Select-Channel Source-Image Pointer
This is a pointer to the channel-of-interest within the first pixel of the source image.  E.g.  if pSrc is the
pointer to the first pixel inside the ROI of a three channel image. Using the appropriate select-channel copy
primitive one could copy the second channel of this source image into the first channel of a destination
image given by pDst by offsetting the pointer by one:
nppiCopy_8u_C3CR(pSrc + 1, nSrcStep, pDst, nDstStep, oSizeROI);"

*Note: this works without multiplying by the number of bytes per data element because the compiler is aware of the data type of the pointer, and calculates the address accordingly.

In C and C++, pointer arithmetic can be accomplished as above or by the notation &ptr[offset] (to return device memory address of data instead of value, value will not work on device memory from host side code).  When using either notation the size of the data type is automatically handled, and the offset is specified as a number of data elements rather than bytes.